# Handling server unavailability with WebClient

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-webflux, webclient, unknown-host

I am using a Spring 5 `WebClient` to interact with a REST server. I understand how to handle the case of a 4xx or 5xx error returned by the server. What I don't understand is how to handle the case of a non-response, for example when the server is down or when the server URL is incorrect. How should I configure the `WebClient`? It must handle a `WebClientRequestException` that wraps an `UnknownHostException`.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(someServerUrl)
    .build();
                
webClient
    .get()
    .uri("/api/something")
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, errorHandlerFor4xx)
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, errorHandlerFor5xx)
    .bodyToMono(SomeStuff.class)
```

Does anybody have a clue?